# MySQL Select - Sort by best match with multiple OR operators

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, select

I have a query:

```
$get_co = 'example';
$get_co_domain = 'example.com';

$getmerid = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,domain,name,alternative_name,company_name,trading_name FROM companies 
WHERE (title = '$get_co')
OR (domain = '$get_co_domain')
OR (name = '$get_co')
OR (alternative_name = '$get_co')
OR (company_name = '$get_co')
OR (trading_name  = '$get_co')
LIMIT 0, 1");
```

In my table, lets say I have 2 entries both with the title 'example', but the domains are 'example.com' and 'example.co.uk'.

Currently it will only match one of these due to the LIMIT, but it may pick the 'example.co.uk' row.

Is there a way I can sort the results in a scoring type way so that it would pick the most relevant based upon certain criteria, ie the domain or company_name.

Comment: You mean like finding the closest string match?

Comment: Yes, as @infomaniac says, define 'relevance'.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by that? sorry, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Do you want to do a type of fuzzy search which searches your database for "similar" strings and returns them by level of similarity?

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, your query can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT id
     , title
     , domain
     , name
     , alternative_name
     , company_name
     , trading_name 
  FROM companies 
 WHERE '$get_co' IN(title,name,alternative_name,company_name,trading_name)
    OR domain = '$get_co_domain'
 ORDER
    BY id
 LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For fast fuzzy-text searching, I'd recommend using an algorithm called *Jaro/Winkler*. Encountered this kind of problem myself some years ago - here's a blogpost I wrote. http://dannykopping.com/blog/fuzzy-text-search-mysql-jaro-winkler.

You will be able to sort your results based on a "similarity" factor from 0 - 100%